# Information not showing on a screen after retrieving it from a database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm implementing a function where I retrieve some info from a Firebase database, to then show it on the screen. This is the function I have on a Redux actions file

```
export function getUserEventPreferences() {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const userId = auth().currentUser.uid;
      const snapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${userId}`).once('value');

      const isAir = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isAir);
      const isAnimals = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isAnimals);
      const isArtAndCulture = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isArtAndCulture);
      const isConcerts = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isConcerts);
      const isEducation = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isEducation);
      const isFood = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isFood);
      const isParty = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isParty);
      const isShopping = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isShopping);
      const isSports = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().isSports);

      const data = {
        isAir,
        isAnimals,
        isArtAndCulture,
        isConcerts,
        isEducation,
        isFood,
        isParty,
        isShopping,
        isSports
      };

      dispatch(showPrefereces(data));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
}
```

Then, on another file, called `UserProfilePreferencesController.js` I call this redux function in the `componentDidMounth` function to retrieve the information

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatchGetMyEventPreferences } = this.props;

    // This is where I call the redux function
    dispatchGetMyEventPreferences();
    this.loadPreferences();
}
```

The issue I have is that, even after retrieving the information, the information does not show on the screen unless I refresh the app. How can I circumvent this issue?

I tried by loading the information on the controller's state (via the `this.loadPreferences()` function), but this doesn't seem to affect anything.

```
loadPreferences = () => {
    const { login } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      isArtAndCulture: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isArtAndCulture,
      isConcerts: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isConcerts,
      isSports: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isSports,
      isFood: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isFood,
      isEducation: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isEducation,
      isAnimals: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isAnimals,
      isParty: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isParty,
      isAir: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isAir,
      isShopping: login.userEventCategoriesPreferences.isShopping
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"componentDidMounth" calls only once in the lifecycle method of any component.

Now why you data is not loading on, because you are fetching data in an async method.
function "this.loadPreferences();" calls after dispatchGetMyEventPreferences but it gets executed before data comes from firebase.

try to return a promise from dispatchGetMyEventPreferences, when data has come from firebase, and then call this.loadPreferences();